# Почему при выделении памяти через malloc выделяеться памяти больше указанного

Tags: c++, winapi

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char *key = (char*)malloc(25);
    if(key != 0)
    {
        SecureZeroMemory(key, 25);
    }
    for(int i = 0;i < 26;i++)
    {
        key[i] = 'a';
    }
    std::cout << lstrlenA(key);
}
```

Вывод

```
38
```

Почему при выделении памяти размер `key` равен 38 если я указываю 25? Дело в `lstrlenA` или в какой-то особенности выделения памяти через malloc?

Comment: `strlen` определяет конец строки по нулевому символу `\0`. Вы его добавили в конец своей строки?

Comment: В С/С++ в общем случае невозможно определить размер памяти по указателю и/или валидность указателя. Приведенный код вместо этого дважды выходит за пределы буфера, что является неопределенным поведением.

Answer (score 1):

Вы выделили 25 байт, все их забили символом `a`, т.е. у вас вышло в памяти что-то вроде

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa#@%$@@#^$^^%^%$^%#%^^%$#%...
```

где после `a` идет что-то, что записано в памяти за пределами выделенного вам места. Может, мусор, может, служебные данные менеджера памяти.

`lstrlenA` ищет количество символов от насчала строки, переданной как указатель в функции, и до первого нулевого символа, обозначающего конец строки. Вы в свои 25 байт такой символ не писали, так что функция пошла искать дальше, за пределами - уже В ЧУЖОЙ памяти.

Вы просто неверно интерпретируете возвращаемый функцией результат.

Comment: А если до конца  рамы и своповов не будет нул терминатора?) сигсигв поймаем же )